# What is _DEFAULT_CA_CERTS in pynsq and tornado

Tags: python, tornado, pynsq

I'm getting this error:

[image]

But I can't figure out what `_DEFAULT_CA_CERTS` is nor how to resolve this problem. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pynsq depended on some non-public variables in Tornado that were removed in Tornado 5.0. For now, you'll need to downgrade to Tornado 4.5.3 and wait for pynsq to update for compatibility with Tornado 5.

Comment: further googling revealed the bug report on pynsq. thank you very much!